# Array of objects from C# to PHP via SOAP web service

Tags: c#, php, .net, soap

I am creating a little web service and I have problems sending an array of objects from a C# application to the web service. I create an object in C# that has different properties, one of these properties is an array of another type of objects. The C# side seems to work fine, but on the PHP side things are not working out. The object arrives at the service with all properties but the array is always empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Types in my WSDL

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost//soap/myService.wsdl">
      <xsd:complexType name="SubObject">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="VAL1" type="xsd:integer" />
          <xsd:element name="VAL2" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="VAL3" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost/soap/myService.wsdl">
      <xsd:complexType name="TestObject">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="PROP1" type="xsd:integer" />
          <xsd:element name="PROP2" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="PROP3" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="MyArray" type="tns:SubObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types
```

What I'm doing in C#:

```
MyService.Test_PortTypeClient client = new MyService.Test_PortTypeClient();
MyService.TestObject curObject = new MyService.TestObject();
curObject.PROP1= 12345;
curObject.PROP2= "test";
curObject.PROP3= "test";

curObject.MyArray = new MyService.SubObject[1];

curObject.MyArray[0] = new MyService.SubObject();
curObject.MyArray[0].VAL1 = 12345;
curObject.MyArray[0].VAL2 = "test";
curObject.MyArray[0].VAL2 = "test";

client.SaveObject(curObject);
```

print_r of the object that's coming from the C# application:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [PROP1] => 12345
    [PROP2] => "test"
    [MyArray] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [PROP3] => "test"
)
```

server.php

```
function SaveProduct($object) {
  // Save
}

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$server = new SoapServer('myService.wsdl');

$server->addFunction("SaveObject");

$server->handle();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm also working on a project with C# and PHP, but I use a WCF webservice. I think you should rather take a look at that..

Comment: I'm not ready to give up on this yet. Everything but the arrays are working fine, so if I could just get this working I'd be done.

Comment: Ok, can you show your PHP where you request the array?

Comment: What do you mean? The server script itself with the saveObject function? I can edit that in.